# Не работает API пост запрос на контроллер. Angular 7, NET Core

Tags: angular2, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Странная ситуация...без изменений то отправка на апишку работает..то нет..что самое интресное..когда отправка не работает то вообще не оправляет на контроллер на бек енд..в браузере нету в нетворке ничего...бут-то просто кнопка. Через какое-то время, запрос снова идет. На фронте нет никаких траблов. Метод сервиса апи вызывается правильно. Вся модель заполнена и совпадает с валидацией на бек енде. В консоль выводил прям пере вызовом апи. Метод вызывается исправно.

Вот код фронта

```
onSubmitProfile() {
if(this.profileForm.valid){
  this.apiCallService.registerUser(this.user);
}
}
```

далее вызывается метод что ведет на апишку

```
registerUser(userDTO: User) : Observable<any>  {
return this.http.post('api/user/register-user', userDTO);
}
```

Импорт Http

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}
```

По сути и все...в чем может быть проблема???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы создали только `Observable`-объект.

Сделайте так:

```
onSubmitProfile() {
    if(this.profileForm.valid) {
        this.apiCallService.registerUser(this.user).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает